# What format to use for recording audio?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, audio-recording

I am working on an iPhone application. I am trying to record audio and upload it to my server.

I want to save it in the smallest size. Which format type should I use? Can I record it in mp3 format?

Answer (score 4):

You should start by reading [Audio & Video Starting Point](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/AudioVideoStartingPoint_iOS/_index.html). The supported file formats of iOS are available in table 2-5 [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/CoreAudioEssentials/CoreAudioEssentials.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH10-SW32) - iOS does **not** support recording MP3s.